# How to export SSL certificate from azure to local server?

Tags: ssl, azure, windows-server-2008

I want to move my MVC application from **Azure** to an **in-house server**. How do I export the SSL certificate associated with the App to install it on the local server?

Is it at all possible?

Comment: People who voted to close the question, please could you bother to explain why??!!

Comment: You can export PFX copy of Azure App Service Certificate using PowerShell. See the details here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38836724/export-azure-ssl-certificate/42852941#42852941

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NO. There is no way to get certificate out of Windows Azure. Question is how it (the certificate) appeared in the Azure at first place. It was certainly not uploaded by Microsoft people or some magic. It is a developer who packed the deployment package to include the certificate reference (thumbprint) and service administrator (or co-admin) who uploaded the original certificate in the Azure. So contact that people (whom might be just you?) and ask for the original certificate.

If certificate is lost, contact the original issuer (certification authority) for a copy, if you were the one to originally requested. If you did not originally requested the certificate, there might have been a reason behind that.

Comment: thanks astaykov. I was wandering if i could export pfx rdp'ing the server... it make sense.