# Export certificate in Azure App Services

Tags: azure, certificate, azure-web-app-service

Would it be possible to export a SSL wildcard certificate used for HTTPS connection in Azure app services? The option to export and used the wildcard cert to another server with the same domain name seems to be missing in Azure App Services as seen below:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, there is no way to get **SSl certificate** out of Windows Azure.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12897909/how-to-export-ssl-certificate-from-azure-to-local-server) is a similar post for you to refer to.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways SSL certificates are made available to App Services to be used for https connections.

There's [App Service Certificates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-ssl-certificate?tabs=apex%2Cportal#start-certificate-order). **These are exportable!** This can be confusing because it sounds like the Private Key Certificates tab of the TLS/SSL settings within an App Service but it's actually its own thing in Azure that allows you to buy certificates through GoDaddy. Because you buy it, it's yours, and it would be silly if they didn't allow you to download it.
To export this, you go to the key vault you associated with this purchase and export the certificate from there.

Then there's [free managed certificates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-ssl-certificate?tabs=apex%2Cportal#create-a-free-managed-certificate) within App services. **These are not exportable!** These are the certificates that you can generate with App Service from the Private Key Certificates tab by clicking on *Create App Service Managed Certificate*, provided you can pass domain ownership requirements with DNS records.

Then there's certificates that you provided to App Service yourself by choosing *Upload Certificate* from the Private Key Certificates tab of the TLS/SSL settings within an App Service. Sorry, **you can't get these back out**. It's assumed you'd still have the certificate if you provided it this way in the first place.

Lastly, there's certificates that were imported from Key Vault, by choosing *Import Key Vault Certificate* from the Private Key Certificates tab of the TLS/SSL settings within an App Service. **These are exportable!** Go to the Key Vault where the certificate is stored and export it, just as you would if you purchased a certificate through App Service Certificates.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can export the certificate. Here is the blog post from Microsoft explaining how.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2017/02/24/creating-a-local-pfx-copy-of-app-service-certificate/